# Global variable issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, connection-string

In my web.config I declared many connectionstrings based on different database like this

```
<add name="connect15-16" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database15-16;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect16-17" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database16-17;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect17-18" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database17-18;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect18-19" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database18-19;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
<add name="connect19-20" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Database19-20;User ID=sa;Password=pwd; "/>
```

At the time of login, user has to select appropriate database then based on that selected database software connects to the desired database.

I have created a global class which connects user to desired database like this

```
public static class Connections
{   
     public static SqlConnection Connection {get; set;}    
     public static void Init(string Name)
     {         
         Connection = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
                              .ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
     }
}
```

This is working fine. But When I run it on localhost and multiple user access it then the main problem begins.

If User1 connects to connect15-16 and after some time user2 connects to connect16-17 then the value of Connection variable overites and User1 connects with connect16-17 
automatically. 
I can't use different variables for different users because everywhere in my application I used Connection variable like this:

```
Connections.Connection.Open();
Connections.Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In ASP.Net, Static variables have application scope and it cannot be
>   cannot be instantiated. So that it will lead to concurrency issues as
>   you are facing now. It will be more suitable for windows applications.

If you need to share data across pages for a single user [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) will be the best thing you can access. It helps you to store and retrieve values for a user. But in Your case *I will not prefer session to store connection or connectionString since it opens a big door for attackers*.

I would like to suggest some modifications to the `Connections` class so that you can access the `Connection` across the application. [ by assuming that you have the user name/ Id in the session]

```
 public static class Connections
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, SqlConnection> _Connection = new Dictionary<string, SqlConnection>();
        public static Dictionary<string, SqlConnection> Connection
        {
            get { return _Connection; }
            set { _Connection = value; }
        }
        public static void Init(string Name)
        {
            string user=HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString();
            if (!Connection.ContainsKey(user))
            {
                Connection.Add(user, new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString));
            }
            else
            {
                if (Connection[user] == null)
                {
                    Connection[user] = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**How to use:**

Let `UserId` for user `1` accessing from system `A` be `USR0001` Then call the static method like the following:

```
  Connections.Init("connect15-16"); // To init the connection
  // This will add a connection to the Connection with key USR0001
```

Let `UserId` for user `2` accessing from system `B` be `USR0045` Then call the static method like the following:

```
Connections.Init("connect16-17"); // To init the connection
// This will add a connection to the Connection with key USR0045
```

As a result you will get separate connection for user 1 and user 2.

When ever you want to use the connection you can access them through the following line of code:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = Connections.Connection["UserId"]; // this will be different for different users
```

Or else you can access them directly by calling like this: `Connections.Connection["UserId"].Open()`

Comment: You mean to say that on every page I have to change my code  SqlConnection sqlCon = Connections.Connection["UserId"]; sqlCon.Open();   instead of Connections.Connection.Open();

Comment: no need you can call `open()` like this `Connections.Connection["UserId"].Open()`

Comment: Okay Thanks, let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't create static variable for it, just change your code as follows

```
public class Connections
{
    private SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public void Init(string Name)
    {
        Connection = GetInstance(Name);
    }

    private SqlConnection GetInstance(string Name)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

> If you want to keep it static than you can do it as follows

```
public class Connections
{
    public static SqlConnection Init(string Name)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

> Save the SqlConnection Object Returned in a variable for later use

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property , `Connection` is not accessible inside `Init()`

Comment: @un-lucky is right. not static variable is not accessible inside static method.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi I have edited the answer, it should work fine now

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior of static. So if you want to solve the overwrite issue you need to have different connection for different users.

Comment: can you describe how ?

Comment: Memory allocation for the Static variable will be only once, so whenever you are taking inputs from the user and assigning it to the Connection property of Connections class the old value of the Static member is overridden.

Comment: I know this very well, please tell me the solution.

Comment: Based on the usage of the Static in your case I thought to give the description first to make sure you understand it.

Comment: Now I don't see you will be able to use the Connections.Connection.Open();Connections.Connection.Close(); As the the property is static you are able to call it. To solve the issue you have to make it as non-static so the every user will have different connection.